# Doctrine 1.2 auto-join i18n?

Tags: php, oop, orm, internationalization, doctrine

I would like to extend the i18n behavior, so that it joins the translation table automatically, on any type of query (DQL, relations, getTable).
Additionally it needs to define the default language parameter, so when I do a query without the language set, it falls back to the the default language.
Note: I'm looking for a generalized behavior, so that is applies to all i18n model objects, not to write and override for each of the classes.

Here is an example:
table `product` -> id, category_id, price...
table `product_translation` -> id, lang, name, description...

With the current solution when I do something like this: `Doctrine_Core::getTable('Product')->findAll()`, it gets all the products without joining the translations.
So in the controller I have to loop trough all the records and reapply translated values, with `$product->name = $product->Translation['en']->name`

I would like something like this:

- `Doctrine_Core::getTable('Product')->findAll()` it should get the joined values for lang='en'
- `Doctrine_Core::getTable('Product)->findAll('en')` same as above
- It should also work with relations, so for instance if I have a class User which has many products `$user->Products` it should return a collection with translations included.
- Also something like `$user->Products('en')` should return the collection for other (non-default) languages
- Magic functions would also be nice (if possible)...something like `Doctrine_Core::getTable('Product')->getByCategoryAndLang(1,'en')`

Can anyone help? I'm looking at templates and behaviors, I think that is the way to go, but have no clue how to implement this

**EDIT:** I see there is not much interest in this, so let me try with a simpler question. How do you usually get i18n fields via relations. For instance how can I call `$user->Products` and get the products with loaded translations?

Answer (score 1):

I think that You do not need to extend the standard Doctrine behavior unless You want this fully automatic. But still You can try to do this like we do - we use a DAO (Data Access Object) that returns us concrete Doctrine entity (Doctrine table representation):

```
\DAO::get('Some\Namespace\Classname')
```

where `Classname` stands for table described by PHP class model. Our DAO class creates the instance of `Classname` that is encapsulated into `proxy` (see Design Patterns).

Beyond table class model we create another class for this table that stands above the table model and manipulates with this model. Within this class we write methods like `getProducts($args)`, `getProduct($id)`, `getProductsByCategory($catId)` etc.

I think that this is what You are looking for...

In method `getProducts($args)` You can then implement `->leftJoin()` within DQL that will join the translations table by given `$lang` identificator in `$args` parameter. Simple example (not tested):

```
class Products extends \DAO {
    public function save($item) {
        $item->save();
    }

    public function getProducts($args = array()) {
        $order = array('p.id');

        $result = \Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Some\Namespace\Product p')
            ->where('1 = 1');

        if(!empty($args['lang'])) {
            $result = $result->leftJoin('Some\Namespace\ProductTranslation pt ON pt.product_id = p.id AND pt.language = ?', $args['lang']);
        }

        $result = $result->orderBy($order);

        $result = $result->execute();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then by calling

```
$products = DAO::get('Some\Namespace\Product')->getProducts(array('lang' => 1));
```

You obtain all the products with english translations loaded...

It is not so much automaticated and You have to write Your own DAO class for every model but it is good approach as You have different data definition class (model) and data manipulation class (controller) that needed for MVC/MVP object oriented application architecture...

Comment: Thanks, but what you are suggesting could be done without the DAO. Just declare the ProductTable class, and add getXy methods that do the joining with Translation. Anyway it doesn't solve the problem, because I still can't access those fields with $product->name, but $product->Translation['en']->name

Comment: You cannot access `name` property right through `product` model as it is not described in this model (and is not present in the db table). With my method You get all the columns in one object (within Doctrine_Collection) - and for ONE concrete translation. So looping through `$products = DAO::get('Some\Namespace\Product')->getProducts(array('lang' => 1));` in this way `foreach($products as $product) {...}` You **can** IMHO access `$product->name`. Cannot You?

Comment: Hmm...I don't think you can still access it, like you said it is not  described in modal. What I could do is hydrate it as array, and rearrange the results (remove Translation, and propagate name one level up). This is what I'm using now. But still, I can't see any difference in your method compared to normal defining methods in Table classes